# Switching optimization profiles in TensorRT: bindingIndex 0 is not in profile 1

Tags: c++, tensorrt

I know this question should really be directed at the NVIDIA support team, however they are *incredibly* unhelpful in their support (just have a look at [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/question-about-using-optimization-profiles-bindingindex-0-is-not-in-profile-1/194060) thread here, instead of actually reading the question, they just point you to the generic API docs page, which trust me has no helpful info on it). Rant aside, here's my question:

I am trying to run batch inference with TensorRT while specifying optimization profiles for additional performance.

My network has input shape (-1, 3, 112, 112) meaning it supports dynamic batch sizes.
I am registering several optimization profiles as follows. You can assume that `m_options.optBatchSizes = std::vector<unsigned int>{2, 4, 8};`

```
// Specify the default optimization profile
    IOptimizationProfile* defaultProfile = builder->createOptimizationProfile();
    defaultProfile->setDimensions(inputName, OptProfileSelector::kMIN, Dims4(1, m_inputC, m_inputH, m_inputW));
    defaultProfile->setDimensions(inputName, OptProfileSelector::kOPT, Dims4(1, m_inputC, m_inputH, m_inputW));
    defaultProfile->setDimensions(inputName, OptProfileSelector::kMAX, Dims4(m_options.maxBatchSize, m_inputC, m_inputH, m_inputW));
    config->addOptimizationProfile(defaultProfile);

    // Specify all the optimization profiles.
    for (const auto& optBatchSize: m_options.optBatchSizes) {
        if (optBatchSize == 1) {
            continue;
        }

        if (optBatchSize > m_options.maxBatchSize) {
            throw std::runtime_error("optBatchSize cannot be greater than maxBatchSize!");
        }

        IOptimizationProfile* profile = builder->createOptimizationProfile();
        profile->setDimensions(inputName, OptProfileSelector::kMIN, Dims4(1, m_inputC, m_inputH, m_inputW));
        profile->setDimensions(inputName, OptProfileSelector::kOPT, Dims4(optBatchSize, m_inputC, m_inputH, m_inputW));
        profile->setDimensions(inputName, OptProfileSelector::kMAX, Dims4(m_options.maxBatchSize, m_inputC, m_inputH, m_inputW));
        config->addOptimizationProfile(profile);
    }
```

Later in my code when I am running inference, I am trying to switch the optimization profile based on the batch size. If the batch size matches one of the registered profiles, then I want to switch the profile. You can assume that `m_optProfIndx` is a `std::unordered_map<int, int>` mapping the batch size to the registered `profileIndex`.

```
        // Determine if the batch size is in our optimization profile
        auto it = m_optProfIndx.find(batchSize);
        if (it != m_optProfIndx.end()) {
//             Switch the optimization profile
            m_context->setOptimizationProfileAsync(it->second, m_cudaStream);
        }
        m_context->setBindingDimensions(0, inputDims);
```

When I try running my code, it crashed with error message:

```
IExecutionContext::setBindingDimensions: bindingIndex 0 is not in profile 1. Using bindingIndex = 2 instead.
1: [convolutionRunner.cpp::executeConv::458] Error Code 1: Cudnn (CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
```

It looks like it is crashing on the call to `m_context->setBindingDimensions(0, inputDims);`.
For reference, `inputDims` is defined as follows: `Dims4 inputDims = {static_cast<int32_t>(inputFaceChips.size()), m_inputC, m_inputH, m_inputW};`, where `inputFaceChips.size()` is the current batch size.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part of the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/developer-guide/index.html#work_dynamic_shapes) is here:

> In an engine built from multiple profiles, there are separate binding indices for each profile.

In your code snippet you are always attempting to set `bindingIndex = 0`, instead of querying the proper bindingIndex for the given profile as described in the docs:

> Likewise, if using ICudaEngine::getBindingIndex(name) to get the index for a profile K beyond the first profile (K=0), append “[profile K]“ to the name used in the INetworkDefinition. For example, if the tensor was called “foo“ in the INetworkDefinition, then engine.getBindingIndex(“foo [profile 3]“) returns the binding index of Tensor “foo" in optimization profile 3.

This may not solve all of your issues (as I suspect this is a red herring), but will (hopefully) suppress the initial warning and allow for more directed debugging.

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is between `profileIndex` in this call `bool setOptimizationProfileAsync(int32_t profileIndex, cudaStream_t stream)` vs `bindingIndex` in this call `bool setBindingDimensions(int32_t bindingIndex, Dims dimensions)`

Comment: So I switched the code to this: `m_context->setBindingDimensions(m_engine->getBindingIndex("input"), inputDims);` Note, `"input"` is the tensor input name when registering the optimization profiles. However, `m_engine->getBindingIndex("input")` always returns 0.

Comment: @cyrusbehr Note the second quote from documentation in the above, you need to augment the tensor input name with the profile id to get the proper index.

Comment: @cyrusbehr Regarding your first comment, if my understanding is correct (I am not a CuDNN expert by any means) the profileIndex is the unique identifier for a given optimization profile, of which you can create several for different input dimensions as you have in your code. In my lexicon I would consider these different Networks for different sized inputs or outputs. The bindingIndex refers to the unique identifier of a layer within a given profile.

I'm still learning the details, so my interpretation of the docs may be improper - if I find a definitive source I'll leave a new comment.

Comment: @cyrusbehr Leaving my last comment, though it is improper. The documentation notes bindings are, in essence, buffers for inputs and outputs to networks - not "layers" as I described.

Thus, if you call setBindingDimensions with the wrong binding index, you are setting the wrong buffer to the given size. In your original code you are setting Binding ("buffer") 0 to a certain size (which is only used by, e.g. Profile 0), then using a different Binding ("buffer") in your inference.

See here: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/developer-guide/index.html#opt_profiles_bindings

Comment: Ok I see, looks like I need to try `(“foo [profile 3]“) ` .

Comment: @cyrusbehr Exactly. Let me know if you get your issue sorted.